# incanter charts cannot be found

Tags: charts, clojure, leiningen, incanter

I build a new project using leiningen to test incanter:

```
lein new testincanter
```

Then, in project.clj, I put this:

```
(defproject testincanter "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [incanter "1.5.4"]])
```

Then I start the repl:

```
lein repl
```

everything is good.

Then I do this,

```
(ns testincanter.sample
  (:use (incanter core datasets io optimize charts stats)))
```

Then it returns  exceptions like:

```
java.lang.Exception: namespace 'incanter.charts' not found
```

or

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: createIntegerTickUnits
```

I have tried incanter.core, incanter.datasets, incanter.io... separately,

all work well, except incanter.charts

Comment: that's very strange - I've just used your commands to create & run project, and everything works fine. Can you execute the command `lein deps :tree|grep freechart` and send it to me to alexott at gmail.com? Thanks

Comment: Yes this problem has gone in new project on another computer.

Comment: Thank you a lot! However I do not know why it does not work in old project, lein deps :tree|grep returns [incanter/jfreechart "1.0.13-no-gnujaxp"]

Comment: I don't understand either :-(